# Wood glue or screws for joint?

Tags: wood, outdoor, adhesive, joints

I posted a question about this, and someone mentioned using `Titebond` wood glue for the joints in the following drawing.

My question: for these types of joints, will wood glue create a stronger bond than screws? The purpose of the joint is to hold these together.

[image]

Comment: Stronger than screws?  I didn't read the other comment, but typically you would use glue and screws, right?  So of course that would be stronger than screws alone.

Comment: Wood glue isn't great outdoors. It eventually lets go due to seasonal movement or wood decay. Screws are a must.

Comment: What's the overall structure you're building? What will the final finish be? Do you care about looks?

Comment: if I wanted strength I'd be using 8" screws from the top into the post on a 45 degree angle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glue can be pretty strong when you've got plenty of area (like there), although unless you've got some diagonal bracing, it's going to be wobbly whatever fixing you use.

Most people don't use glue because it takes a while to dry, so you either run out of clamps after a couple of joints, or the clamps get in the way of the next thing. (by comparison you can bang in a few nails and call it done)

If you're worried about the screws rusting, use screws as clamps, and remove them after the glue has dried. Or leave them in and let them rust.

Answer (score 2):

I would use screws, especially since they will be hidden so you don't have to worry about seeing exposed screw heads.

Answer (score 2):

Glue and screw.

The glue seals the gaps, reducing rot risk. The screws will be a more reliable, and quicker, way to fasten them in place.

Square braces are kinda ugly though imo. A diagonal brace (made by cutting a 2*4 at 45° in opposite directions) would be more appealing - again imo. Look, for example, at corner bracing used in post and beam structures.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend getting some standard L-shape brackets or joist-post connectors and screwing them in place. They'll work far better than your chunks of wood there.

Comment: They'll look gross, though. I'd do the wood.

Comment: *ooooh gross*. ;)    Use triangle shaped wood brackets for more surface area to glue and screw and be more visually appealing. ( *there is something very satisfying about saying "glue and screw"* )

Comment: @AlaskaMan  that sounds good to me

Comment: “_glue and screw_”... that’s what she said.